# How to get a Solution name in .Net Core Project

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

How can I get the **Solution** **name** in `.Net Core` project.
I have searched a lot on web but could not find anything

[image]

So how can I get the "**Clean_Architecture**" as a solution name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set breackpoints to check the following code and find which is your solution name.

Try this:

```
var SolutionFullPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).FullName;
var tempStrings = SolutionFullPath.Split('\\'); 

var solutionName = tempStrings[tempStrings.Length - 1];;
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. But better way would be `var solutionName = tempStrings[tempStrings.Length - 1];`

Answer (score -2):

Solution is simply a container for projects and haven't got any special meaning in program context. But you can try following to get the folder of project that maybe the same as solution name:

```
var solutionName = Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

Comment: I have already tried this but this will give me "dotnet.exe".